# InteractiveViewer class in flutter is not defined

Tags: flutter

I was reading about InteractiveViewer from here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html

But when I tried to use InteractiveViewer in my code It gave me an error :-

```
The method 'InteractiveViewer' isn't defined for the type 'MyHomeState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 
'InteractiveViewer'.dartundefined_method
```

My flutter code is below:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = "InteractiveViewer Sample";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(_title),
        ),
        body: MystateLessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MystateLessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: MyHome());
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyHomeState();
  }
}

class MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        minScale: 0.1,
        maxScale: 1.6,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: <Color>[Colors.orange, Colors.red],
              stops: <double>[0.0, 1.0],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My flutter version is `Flutter 1.17.5`
and dart version is  `Dart 2.8.4`

Can you please tell me what is the problem here.

Comment: You need to upgrade your Flutter version to the latest which is `Flutter 1.20`. Read more about the release updates here: https://medium.com/flutter/announcing-flutter-1-20-2aaf68c89c75

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an old version of flutter.

InteractiveViewer was released in `1.20 version of Flutter`

So you need to upgrade your flutter, To upgrade you can use the following command in the command-prompt:-

```
flutter upgrade
```

This command gets the most recent version of the Flutter SDK that’s available on your current Flutter channel.